# How to play songs using bluetooth from mobile to XBMC

Tags: kodi, openelec, bluetooth, media

I have purchased a Raspi v2 and have installed openelec 5.0.5 on it, since I want to use it as a media center. I have a wifi dongle, which works fine even while using airplay.

I have recently purchase a bluetooth dongle for it, but I am not able to configure it. I want to know how do I install the drivers for it. 
Also, once the bluetooth starts working, then I would like to use it to play my songs from my mobile phone to the openelec console, just like how we play it in airplay. So is there any such plug-in to do so ? Or is there any settings/ feature of Kodi I am not aware of?

Comment: What's the bluetooth dongle you are using?

Comment: Its a Enter Mini USB Bluetooth 2.0. If the bluetooth is the issue then I have no problem in replacing it with a new one. My bluetooth is a really old one, may be some 3-4 yrs. Also please let me know what model should I go for.

Comment: I suggest going with ThePihut's V2.0 Nano USB to Bluetooth dongle and this website gives details of installing it: http://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-raspberry-pi-nano-bluetooth-dongle Although you can get models that do wifi as well as bluetooth

Comment: Instead of purchasing a Raspi-Pi 2, WiFi dongle and Bluetooth dongle you should have just got a v3.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is set up your Pi for 'A2DB sink mode'. I found the follwing instructions on [this page](https://thecodeninja.net/2016/06/bluetooth-audio-receiver-a2dp-sink-with-raspberry-pi/):

Start by install / updating all the packages

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth bluez-tools
```

Add users to groups. This is very important. **If using any other distro, replace ‘xbian’ with your username.**

```
sudo gpasswd -a xbian pulse
sudo gpasswd -a xbian lp
sudo gpasswd -a pulse lp
sudo gpasswd -a xbian audio
sudo gpasswd -a pulse audio
```

Set up PulseAudio, Bluetooth Device Class

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'extra-arguments = --exit-idle-time=-1 --log-target=syslog' >> /etc/pulse/client.conf"
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x200420
sudo reboot
```

**Note:** *The Bluetooth service/device class 0x200420 mean the device is set up for Car Audio. See [this link](http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html) to explore more Bluetooth Class options.*

To pair with a device, we will need to use the “bluetoothctl” tool.

```
sudo bluetoothctl
```

Set the agent to KeyboardOnly and make it default. This needs to be done once only. Inside bluetoothctl, run the following commands:
agent KeyboardOnly

```
default-agent
```

Turn on bluetooth on your phone/tablet and make sure it is discoverable. Run the following commands inside bluetoothctl:

```
scan on
pair xx:xx:xx:...
trust xx:xx:xx:...
exit
```

**Note:** *xx:xx:xx:.. is the MAC address of your handset/device. After running ‘scan on’, wait a minute for your device to show up along with it’s MAC address. After running ‘pair xx:xx:xx:..’ check your device and accept the incoming connection. Do the same on terminal by typing yes.*

Now connect to the Raspberry Pi from your handset and it should connect as an audio device. All audio played through the device should now be output using Raspberry Pi’s HDMI or Analog out depending on your Pi’s configuration.

If the connection fails, try again, sometimes it takes 2 attempts.

Comment: Nice but the OP is using OpenElec, which is really specific, compared to raspbian

Comment: @JB I've used OpenElec, it uses apt / is based on Debian... the configuration should be the same as long as a blue tooth module is installed.  FTA: "Other compatible bluetooth modules should work as well."